# Unknown Ruby error when running rake db:create I am on raspberry pi running the latest version of it's os

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, raspberry-pi3

So I've been following this blog to get my ruby on rails server setup. Everything has been great except for a few bugs here or there. However, when I run rake db:create I get this odd bug

```
ea000-76feb000 rw-p 00021000 b3:02 352        /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so
7e6a6000-7eea5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
7ef7a000-7ef7b000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [sigpage]
7ef7b000-7ef7c000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [vvar]
7ef7c000-7ef7d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]


[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
ABORTED
```

I'm not quite sure what the bug is or why I can't see what the exact error is. The cli looks like the first 4 lines just repreated with various different foloders and no explanation

Comment: That's a bug in Ruby and, as the error indicates, you should report it at that location if you can't resolve it otherwise. Are you running the latest version of Ruby? If not, consider upgrading to see if that fixes it.

Comment: It's also possible this is a bug in a compiled Ruby extension, but given the limited information here it's not clear if that's the case. What's the minimum amount of code that reproduces this issue?

Comment: All it takes is `rake db:create`

Comment: If you can make a minimal project that reproduces that it's worth reporting the bug. Hard to say at a distance what the issue is, but things like the MySQL or Postgres driver could be at fault. That trace doesn't show enough detail.